# Application to include an executable which ask user input in command prompt. Want to automate so that no cmd prompt opens

Tags: c++, wpf, windows, c#-4.0, win32-process

I have a WPF application in which I want to integrate a module. the other module is an executable which when clicked prompts for user response. Based on the user response it will process or exit:

for eg:

```
C:\>Abc.exe press enter
> command1 
//Executing command1  -- command1 will create a log file
>exit
//Exits the Abc.exe process
C:\>
```

So I want to integrate this part into my WPf application. When a button is in WPF application, above steps are executed automatically.

i have no idea on how to execute shell prompt which required user input.

```
Process process1 = new Process();
            process1.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\abc.exe";
            process1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            process1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            process1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process1.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            process1.Start();
            StreamWriter inputWriter = process1.StandardInput;
            process1.StandardInput.WriteLine("command1");
            process1.StandardInput.Flush();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);
            process1.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
            process1.StandardInput.Flush();

            process1.Kill();
```

But it opens up the abc.exe in console, but does not execute the commands i.e. command1 and exit.

Comment: From the [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page of the StackOverflow Help Center: *Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.*

Comment: You use the Process class with redirect stdin and stdout.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have updated my question with the code i tried, but it does not seems to be working.

Comment: @Sheridan Sorry for not putting the solution i tried, I have updated my question

Comment: Thank you and it's not a problem... we've all got to start somewhere. You'll find that you get more help if you follow the advice from the StackOverflow Help Center.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it in WPF, but in Win32 you would use `CreateProcess()` with redirected input/output so you can send your own input data and read any output data as needed.

[How to spawn console processes with redirected standard handles](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190351)

[Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: No need to use Win32 here. It's all wrapped by Process